# Is a Mac Eclipse project able to be run on a Windows PC with Eclipse installed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't HAVE to be able to edit it on Windows, but I do have to be able to run the program made using the mac version of Eclipse on Windows. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, it should work perfectly fine :)

Comment: I really don't understand what is the sense of your question ...

Comment: Great question!  I created 2 Java projects on Windows Eclipse, one a JAR library, and one a window application.  The JAR library exports fine on the Mac, but the window application has a ton of library reference errors (looks like it baked the Windows path in using Windows path conventions), and I don't know how to resolve those references and fix it so it compiles on the Mac.  At least, that is my take on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Java runs on any system with a JVM, so yes.